# How to sort a sorted vector while maintaining the previous orders

Tags: c++

I have following structure

```
struct Mydate
{
 int  UserId;
 string name;

};
vector<Mydate> v1;
```

1:  sort the vector by UserId

2:  Sort the sorted vector by name  while maintaining  the  previous order 
For example

```
v1.push_back(make_pair(100, "d"));
v1.push_back(make_pair(100, "q")); 
v1.push_back(make_pair(102, "m"));
v1.push_back(make_pair(102, "d"));
v1.push_back(make_pair(100, "c"));
```

( sort function can be used first for UserId  but when we sort it agin by name, it override the previous order)

can we see output in follwoing format:

```
(100,c) , (100, d), (100, q), (102,d), (102, m)
```

Please can some one help me out??

Comment: You need to create an `operator<` for your struct or a compare functor that does the same thing.  And then you can use `std::sort`.

Comment: What do you mean by "maintaining previous order"?

Comment: @jensa I think he means that they need to be sorted on both UserId and then name.

Comment: @AnonMail Ah, yeah then a custom comparision function is the way to go.

Comment: In C++11 the idiomatic way of implementing such custom comparison functions is using `std::tie`, see for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18437891/3959454)

Comment: Thanks a lot u guys!

Comment: An appropriate comparison operator is probably the best solution here. However, you might also want to look up stable sort, which is advantageous if you want to perform one sort after another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an `operator<` member function like this:

```
operator<(const Mydate & rhs)
{
    if (UserId < rhs.UserId)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (UserId == rhs.UserId)
    {
        if (name < rhs.name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @LogicStuff I can shrink the code at the expense of clarity. Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: I think the code will remain clear after that, if not clearer. No need for another answer.

Comment: Not sure what LogicStuff said, but I feel like it was probably to replace everything after the first `if{...}` with `return UserId == rhs.UserId && name < rhs.name`. Which yes, would be shorter, and probably less clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own comparator for `std::sort`

```
vector<Mydate> v1;
// ...
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [](Mydate const &a, Mydate const &b) {
    return (a.UserId == b.UserId)? (a.name < b.name) : (a.UserId < b.UserId);});
```

Or instead of a class you can use a `std::pair`:

```
using Mydate = std::pair<int, std::string>;
```

`std::pair`s are compared lexicographically which is what you want. And then use `std::sort` as:

```
std::vector<Mydate> v1;
//...
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Comment: You have a typo in your lambda. You are comparing `a.UserId` with itself instead of `b.UserId`, twice.

Comment: @101010 :-) I see you have also cleaned up the code. And the suggestion to use `std::pair` is a good one. +1!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

struct Mydate
{
    int  UserId;
    std::string name;
};

std::vector<Mydate> v1;

int main()
{
    v1.push_back( { 100, "d" } );
    v1.push_back( { 100, "q" } ); 
    v1.push_back( { 102, "m" } );
    v1.push_back( { 102, "d" } );
    v1.push_back( { 100, "c" } );

    std::sort( v1.begin(), v1.end(),
               []( const Mydate &a, const Mydate &b ) 
               { 
                   return std::tie( a.UserId, a.name ) < std::tie( b.UserId, b.name );
               } );

    for ( const Mydate &item : v1 ) 
    {
        std::cout << item.UserId << '\t' << item.name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
100 c
100 d
100 q
102 d
102 m
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom comparator approach is preferred one, but, for sake of completeness, multiple sorting approach should be mentioned. Sometimes it might be preferred (usually when you want to be able to choose sorting rules dynamically).

To sort entries by some property A, where elements with same A would be sorted by property B, you need to use bottoms-up approach: sort by B first, then sort by A, preserving relative order of equivalent elements (stable sort).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Mydate
{
    int  UserId;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Mydate> v {{100, "d"}, {100, "q"}, {102, "m"}, {102, "d"}, {100, "c"}};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(),        [](auto& l, auto& r){return l.name   < r.name;});
    std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& l, auto& r){return l.UserId < r.UserId;});
    for(const auto& d: v)
        std::cout << d.UserId << ' ' << d.name << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on sorting in 2 passes, use [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) for the second pass.